# Replace names of variable into the same column and join with other table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

How to replace multiples names into the same column and join with other table?

I have to join 2 tables but the problem in the first table I have a variable (VAR) that is equal with the other (VAR1), I have to replace different things:

I have to convert all uppercase, I have to change:

- `'transform_'` should match `'_TRANS_'`
- `'_difference_'` should match `'_DIF_'`
- `'_upper_'` should match `'_UPP_'`

AN EXAMPLE:

Table T

```
id  var
-----------------------
1   col_difference_tr
2   pro_transform_rd
3   cap_upper_ld
```

Table S

```
process  var1
-------------------------
32       COL_DIF_TR
45       PRO_TRANS_RD
32       CAP_UPP_LD
```

Then to get cross and coincided with the other table, I have already tried this:

```
SELECT A.* , IV.VALUE, VAR
FROM TABLA_T  A 
LEFT JOIN TABLA_S IV ON  REPLACE(UPPER(IV.VAR),'_transform_', '_TRANS_')=
A.VAR1
 LEFT JOIN TABLA_S IV ON  REPLACE(UPPER(IV.VAR),'_difference_', '_DIF_')= 
A.VAR1
 LEFT JOIN TABLA_S IV ON  REPLACE(UPPER(IV.VAR),'_upper_', '_UPP_')= 
A.VAR1
```

so the final tables have to look like this:

```
id  process  var1
----------------------------
1   32       COL_DIF_TR
2   45       PRO_TRANS_RD
3   32       CAP_UPP_LD
```

Comment: Please add your DBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps what you want is a more complicated `JOIN` condition?

```
SELECT A.*, IV.VALUE, IV.VAR
FROM TABLA_T  A LEFT JOIN
     TABLA_S IV
     ON  A.VAR1 IN (REPLACE(UPPER(IV.VAR), '_transform_', '_TRANS_'),
                    REPLACE(UPPER(IV.VAR), '_difference_', '_DIF_'),
                    REPLACE(UPPER(IV.VAR), '_upper_', '_UPP_')
                   );
```

This may not be efficient.  You might also find a single `replace()` is best:

```
SELECT A.*, IV.VALUE, IV.VAR
FROM TABLA_T  A LEFT JOIN
     TABLA_S IV
     ON  A.VAR1 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(IV.VAR), '_transform_', '_TRANS_'), '_difference_', '_DIF_'), '_upper_', '_UPP_');
```

Answer (score 0):

if the requirement is on oracle-plsql, then we can directly use decode function in where condition

```
DECODE(IV.VAR,
 '_transform_', '_TRANS_',
 '_difference_', '_DIF_',
 '_upper_', '_UPP_',
 IV.VAR) = A.VAR1;
```